How to Display Fixed Y-axis Range and Hide Non-Integer Values on the Y-axis in a Matplotlib Plot?
Given plot like this:

Here is the code:
#@title Visualizer Function

def plot_delineation_comparison(Xt, yt, Xp, yp, start, stop=None, rec_name = '-', lead_name = '-', pathology_name = '-'):

  if stop is None:
    stop = -1

  Xt = Xt[start:stop]
  yt = yt[start:stop]
  Xp = Xp[start:stop]
  yp = yp[start:stop]

  # Get mask of every class for prediction
  bl_pred = yp == 0
  p_pred = yp == 1
  qrs_pred = yp == 2
  t_pred = yp == 3

  # Get mask of every class for ground truth
  bl_true = yt == 0
  p_true = yt == 1
  qrs_true = yt == 2
  t_true = yt == 3

  # Create figure with two rows and one column
  fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(
    2,
    1,
    figsize=(16, 8),
    sharex=True,
    gridspec_kw={"hspace": 0},
  )

  # Plotting for prediction
  prev_class = None
  start_idx = 0
  for i in range(stop - start):
    current_class = None
    if bl_pred[i]:
      current_class = 'grey'
    elif p_pred[i]:
      current_class = 'orange'
    elif qrs_pred[i]:
      current_class = 'green'
    elif t_pred[i]:
      current_class = 'purple'

    if current_class != prev_class:
      if prev_class is not None:
        ax2.axvspan(start_idx, i, color=prev_class, alpha=0.5)
      start_idx = i
      prev_class = current_class
  # Fill the last region
  if prev_class is not None:
      ax2.axvspan(start_idx, stop - start, color=prev_class, alpha=0.5)

  # Plotting for ground truth
  prev_class = None
  start_idx = 0
  for i in range(stop - start):
    current_class = None
    if bl_true[i]:
      current_class = 'grey'
    elif p_true[i]:
      current_class = 'orange'
    elif qrs_true[i]:
      current_class = 'green'
    elif t_true[i]:
      current_class = 'purple'

    if current_class != prev_class:
      if prev_class is not None:
        ax1.axvspan(start_idx, i, color=prev_class, alpha=0.5)
      start_idx = i
      prev_class = current_class
  # Fill the last region
  if prev_class is not None:
    ax1.axvspan(start_idx, stop - start, color=prev_class, alpha=0.5)

  # First row for ground truth (X_unseen, y_true)
  ax1.plot(Xt, color='blue')
  ax1.set_ylabel('Ground Truth')

  # draw baseline at y=0
  ax1.axhline(y=0, color='red', linestyle='-', lw=0.5)

  # Second row for ground truth (X_pred y_pred)
  ax2.plot(Xp, color='blue')
  ax2.axhline(y=0, color='red', linestyle='-', lw=0.5)
  ax2.set_xlim([0, stop - start])
  ax2.set_ylabel('Prediction')
  ax2.set_xlabel('Index')

  # Retrieve the current x-tick locations
  current_xticks = ax2.get_xticks()

  # Define the new x-tick labels based on absolute start and end
  new_xtick_labels = [int(x + start) for x in current_xticks]

  with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", UserWarning)
    ax2.set_xticklabels(new_xtick_labels)

  cm = ConfusionMatrix(actual_vector=yt.flatten(), predict_vector=yp.flatten(), transpose=True)

  # Handle if not number type
  cm.PPV = [0 if not type(x) == float else x for _,x in cm.PPV.items()]
  cm.TPR = [0 if not type(x) == float else x for _,x in cm.TPR.items()]

  # Make length of PPV and TPR consistent, fill with zero if not
  if len(cm.PPV) < 4:
    cm.PPV += [0] * (4 - len(cm.PPV))
  if len(cm.TPR) < 4:
    cm.TPR += [0] * (4 - len(cm.TPR))
  if len(cm.F1) < 4:
    # convert F1 to list and fixed it with length 4
    cm.F1 = list(cm.F1.values())
    cm.F1 += [0] * (4 - len(cm.F1))

  notes_list = [
    f"Recall",
    f"BL         : {cm.TPR[0]:.2f}",
    f"P          : {cm.TPR[1]:.2f}",
    f"QRS        : {cm.TPR[2]:.2f}",
    f"T          : {cm.TPR[3]:.2f}",
    f"",
    f"Rec Name   : {rec_name}",
    f"Lead       : {lead_name}",
    f"Pathology  : {pathology_name}",
    f"Unit       : mV",
    f"Sample Rate: 360Hz",
    f"SNR(Pr./GT): {calculate_snr(Xp, Xt)}dB",
    f"",
    f"Precission",
    f"BL         : {cm.PPV[0]:.2f}",
    f"P          : {cm.PPV[1]:.2f}",
    f"QRS        : {cm.PPV[2]:.2f}",
    f"T          : {cm.PPV[3]:.2f}",
  ]

  # notes_list += catatan

  ax1.set_title(f"F1-Score | BL: {cm.F1[0]:.2f} | P: {cm.F1[1]:.2f} | QRS: {cm.F1[2]:.2f} | T: {cm.F1[3]:.2f}")

  code_font = FontProperties(family='monospace', style='normal', variant='normal', size=8)

  for i, note in enumerate(notes_list[:]):
    plt.text(1.01, 0.95 - i * 0.1, note, transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=10, va='top', ha='left', fontproperties=code_font)

  # for i, note in enumerate(notes_list[5:]):
    # plt.text(1.01, 0.95 - i * 0.1, note, transform=ax2.transAxes, fontsize=10, va='top', ha='left', fontproperties=code_font)

  plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.5)

  # add legend with offset


  # Create custom Line2D objects with desired colors
  custom_lines = [
    Line2D([0], [0], color='grey', lw=4, alpha=0.5),
    Line2D([0], [0], color='orange', lw=4, alpha=0.5),
    Line2D([0], [0], color='green', lw=4, alpha=0.5),
    Line2D([0], [0], color='purple', lw=4, alpha=0.5)
  ]

  # Add legend with custom lines
  ax1.legend(custom_lines, ['BL', 'P', 'QRS', 'T'], loc='upper left')

  plt.show()

I'm working on visualizing some data using Matplotlib, and I've encountered an issue with how the y-axis is displayed. Specifically, I have a plot where the y-axis shows non-integer values, and I would like to hide these non-integer values so that only integers are displayed.
Additionally, I need to fix the y-axis range between -2 and 2 for both the first and second rows of subplots in the figure. The goal is to maintain consistency in the y-axis range across these subplots.

What do you mean by you would like only integers to be displayed? Looking at your plots your data seems to be all floats. Concerning your y-axis issue, you can set the limits like you already did for the x-axis, e.g. ax1.set_ylim([-2, 2]) and ax2.set_ylim([-2, 2]).

@Flow the data is indeed float, but the displayed y label is float.

For your usecase plt.yticks([-2,-1,0,1,2]) will do. For some more general options see answers to this question.
